# Angular2 module system with TS

Tags: angular, typescript

I was looking at this : https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed in order to understand the Angular Module System in its most basic form.

In this seed project there is a `SharedModule` which has both `index.ts` and `shared.module.ts`. In `shared.module.ts` it does the exports the Angular way - with directives, exports, providers and etc. In `index.ts` it reexports them. In `app.module.ts` it imports `SharedModule.forRoot()` which is perfect - this registeres the `NameListService` to be available to the whole application. However when the `NameListService` is to be used it has to be imported and this is done via `import { NameListService } from '../shared/index';` as presented in `home.component.ts` which by the way is part of the `home.module.ts` which also imports the `SharedModule`.

According to me this is totally wrong.

Why would I have to import it like this - this breaks modularity - what if I am using a module which I have not written and thus do not know where exactly to look for a file ?

Why would I then bother with creating and registering things in `shared.module.ts` if then I will have to use them via the `shared/index.ts` instead of just using the `shared/index.ts` ?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question has been answer over on Angular's website: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-ng-vs-js-modules

I would recommend reading https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html for an in depth guide on ngModules

**Update**

Try and think of it in terms of the two different compilers: the angular compiler and the typescript compiler.

The fact you reference the UserService by path allows the typescript compiler to find it. If it couldn't find the UserService, your code would not compile. It also provides you with intellisense and type checking. The angular compiler doesn't care about this.

Adding the UserService to ngModule allows the Angular compiler to create an instance of it and provide it to your components, services etc. If you did not do this you would get an error saying something like: "no provider found for UserService"

Comment: Yes. I know this yet it feels kind of strange( unnecessary ) to use both systems side by side without them communicating with each other. My problem with the example above is that I have to specify where the UserService is via path even though it is part of a valid Angular module.